Auto-delete asp .net project file (Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS )
There are a few projects in storage.
I shutdown the PC and re-start it next morning. All files of  project folder are gone. There are show folders only
(controller,view,Models,bin). There are no project files available.
How to solved this error in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Ubuntu don't automatically delete files at shutdown/(re)boot, except maybe for /tmp and other in-memory-filesystems. Please be more specific. What is the path to your project directory, is it remote mounted, any other info about your setup ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
